# Playing video in iPad application from server

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, media-player

I want to play a video which is uploaded to the server from an iPad application, but when the screen loads it gives an error:

> An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer

I am using the following code:

```
    -(void)playVideo{




     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas.com.pk/emrapp/test.mp4"];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:mp];    

mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
[mp release];


NSLog(@"Successfully playing thanks");
     }


   -(void)playbackFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)notification{

MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:movie];
[movie release];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://celeritas.com.pk/emrapp/test.mp4 the URL seems to be wrong...

> The requested URL /emrapp/test.mp4 was not found on this server.

Any way this will work

.h

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController * plyr;
 NSURL * url;


@property (nonatomic,retain) MPMoviePlayerViewController *plyr;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSURL *url;
```

.m

```
@synthesize plyr ;
@synthesize url;

     url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"valid url"];          
    plyr = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

Comment: giving this error -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ad4c30

Answer (score 1):

Url might be wrong double check that video url link is accessible, secondly do see your network firewall this might also cause problem.

The one tweak you can change instead of:

```
mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

use:

```
mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
```

Comment: when I try to play audio stream, I need to set the movieSourceType to MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown

Answer (score 0):

try this

create object of MPMoviePlayerViewController in .h like  **MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp;**

```
#import<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
[[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
[[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
[[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Code

```
    -(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender  
    {  

      NSURL  *fileURL =  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Qjh56woQMw"];  

     MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]         initWithContentURL:fileURL];  

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                        selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)  
                                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                       object:moviePlayerController];  

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
[moviePlayerController play];  
  } 

    - (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification  
    {  
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];  
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotificationobject:moviePlayerController];
    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];  
    [moviePlayerController release];  
}
```

Comment: this is for local file i need from server